# ARM assembly unmatched push pop

Tags: android, assembly, arm

I have a function where the push/pop counts don't seem to match up.  Is this normal?

```
disassemble /m
Dump of assembler code for function TouchState::GetModifierKeys() const:
141 {
   0x5d718b64 <+0>: push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, lr}

142     Grip<TouchStateImpl> grip_this;
143 
144     Impl::SureGetGrip(*this, grip_this);
   0x5d718b68 <+4>: movs    r2, #128    ; 0x80
   0x5d718b6a <+6>: mov r1, sp
   0x5d718b70 <+12>:    lsls    r2, r2, #18
   0x5d718b7e <+26>:    bl  0x5d718984 <Impl::SureGetGrip<TouchStateImpl>(Object const&, Grip<TouchStateImpl>&, int)>

145     if(grip_this->valid_flags.any(TouchStateImpl::modifier_keys_valid))
   0x5d718b84 <+32>:    ldr r1, [pc, #84]   ; (0x5d718bdc <TouchState::GetModifierKeys() const+120>)
   0x5d718b86 <+34>:    adds    r0, r4, #0
   0x5d718b88 <+36>:    add r1, pc
   0x5d718b8a <+38>:    adds    r0, #40 ; 0x28
   0x5d718b8c <+40>:    ldr r1, [r1, #0]
   0x5d718b8e <+42>:    bl  0x5d67d55c <Extended_Bitfield<7558u, unsigned int, 1u>::any(Extended_Bitfield_Constant<7558u, unsigned int, 1u> const&) const>
   0x5d718b92 <+46>:    cmp r0, #0
   0x5d718b94 <+48>:    beq.n   0x5d718ba4 <TouchState::GetModifierKeys() const+64>

146         return grip_this->modifier_keys;
   0x5d718b96 <+50>:    adds    r4, #112    ; 0x70
   0x5d718b98 <+52>:    ldrh    r4, [r4, #0]

147     else
148         throw InvalidObjectException();
   0x5d718b9a <+54>:    mov r0, sp
   0x5d718b9c <+56>:    bl  0x5d718a64 <Grip<TouchStateImpl>::~Grip()>
   0x5d718ba4 <+64>:    movs    r0, #8
   0x5d718ba6 <+66>:    blx 0x5da2eac8
   0x5d718baa <+70>:    ldr r1, [pc, #52]   ; (0x5d718be0 <TouchState::GetModifierKeys() const+124>)
   0x5d718bac <+72>:    adds    r4, r0, #0
   0x5d718bae <+74>:    add r1, pc
   0x5d718bb0 <+76>:    bl  0x5d646da4 <InvalidObjectException::InvalidObjectException(char const*)>
   0x5d718bb4 <+80>:    ldr r1, [pc, #44]   ; (0x5d718be4 <TouchState::GetModifierKeys() const+128>)
   0x5d718bb6 <+82>:    ldr r2, [pc, #48]   ; (0x5d718be8 <TouchState::GetModifierKeys() const+132>)
   0x5d718bb8 <+84>:    adds    r0, r4, #0
   0x5d718bba <+86>:    add r1, pc
   0x5d718bbc <+88>:    add r2, pc
   0x5d718bbe <+90>:    ldr r1, [r1, #0]
   0x5d718bc0 <+92>:    ldr r2, [r2, #0]
   0x5d718bc2 <+94>:    blx 0x5da2eaf8
   0x5d718bc6 <+98>:    adds    r0, r4, #0
   0x5d718bc8 <+100>:   blx 0x5da2eb04
   0x5d718bcc <+104>:   b.n 0x5d718bce <TouchState::GetModifierKeys() const+106>
   0x5d718bce <+106>:   mov r0, sp
   0x5d718bd0 <+108>:   bl  0x5d718a64 <Grip<TouchStateImpl>::~Grip()>
   0x5d718bd4 <+112>:   blx 0x5da2ea4c
   0x5d718bd8 <+116>:   subseq  r12, pc, r0, ror pc ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
   0x5d718bdc <+120>:   subseq  r12, pc, r8, asr #15
   0x5d718be0 <+124>:   umaaleq pc, r9, r12, r12    ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
   0x5d718be4 <+128>:   subseq  r11, pc, lr, lsl r9 ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
   0x5d718be8 <+132>:   subseq  r11, pc, r0, lsr #18

149 }
   0x5d718ba0 <+60>:    adds    r0, r4, #0
   0x5d718ba2 <+62>:    pop {r1, r2, r3, r4, pc}
```

This is from a release build, and a crash happens when returning from this function.  The class/struct it returns only contains a `short` (2 bytes).  If I change the struct to contain an `int` instead, the crash doesn't happen.

I just started learning about ARM asm, and learned about the lr register.  I've looked at another function, and the push/pop pairs count matches up.  In this case, there are 6 registers pushed, and 5 popped.  To confuse matters even more, when I make the return struct size `int`, the disassembly then has:

```
   0x5d718b4c <+0>:     push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, lr}
   0x5d718b9e <+82>:    pop     {r4, pc}
```

So, I'm not really sure if I'm just pushing (or popping :p) the problem elsewhere.

Additionally, I've read from this site that `pops` are really `LDMIA SP!,{...}`, but I didn't see that opcode.

Comment: You should show the original C++ code, especially the class declaration.  It is normal to have multiple `pop` statements.  As the *epilogue* is fairly concise for the ARM, the compiler will often generate multiple `return` points even if the source only has one.  Otherwise it would do a branch which may be as many instructions as the *epilogue*.  When returning structures, they are placed on the stack, so your generated code doesn't look completely out of sorts.  Attach a debugger and pin-point where the program crashes.

Comment: Yeah, that disassemble was from running in gdb.  It complained about accessing memory location 0x1 after returning from that function, then would crash with a trashed callstack.  Only got this problem on a Galaxy S3, but it was resolved after moving to NDK r9.

Comment: Any chance it's an old compiler? I've had a similar issue regarding interrupt handlers on an old gcc.